# xml file validated before XQuery query starts

Tags: xquery

i have a question related to the validation of an XML file against the schema 1.1. In some XQuery implementations 
it is ok to use it in the prologue:       *import schema namespace r = "http://example.org" at "schemaABC.xsd";* 
and later on via a validate expression to have the xml file validated (or not). 
Is this the only way ? I am asking it because not all XQuery implementations are aware of the xsd 1.1 features and the Saxon EE is over the budget.

Is it possible to have the xml validated (and all type annotations in place, of course) before starting the XQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking four different questions.

1. do XQuery implementations support XSD 1.1 as well as XSD 1.0?
   Some do, some do not.
2. is the prolog evaluated before starting the XQuery
   No, the prolog is part of the query.
3. can I use validate expressions in my query?
   Yes.
4. are validate expressions the only way to validate XML data?
   No. An XQuery implementation might allow other ways, such as requiring that XML documents be schema-valid before importing them into a database; you could also use XProc, the XML Pipeline Language, to do a validate before running XQuery.